# How to edit a Gridview column font from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to edit certain column font size

```
/*Line 47*/  GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "";
/*Line 48*/  GridView1.Columns[0].ControlStyle.Font.Size= 40; // the bug is here
/*Line 49*/  GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Text = "Report Name";
```

Line 48 gives error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

Answer (score 0):

Columns property references the columns in your grid-view setup, if you wanted to just access a targeted column in a specific row then:

```
GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].ControlStyle.Font.Size = 40;
```

Would be used, otherwise you may as well just set the ControlStyle in your column when you construct it (either in code or designer).

Comment: Thanks Mantorok,
But this line will change only the first line, except if I used loop
I want to adjust the column with one line (more faster)..

Comment: Yes I put the zeros in just as an example, if you want to change all items in a column you just need to change the ControlStyle either in the mark-up or the code which adds it programmatically, how are you adding the columns?

Answer (score 0):

//First Use Header File

using System.Drawing;

// than

```
 BridView1.ControlStyle.Font.Size = 9;
```